# Can I use hexcode of colours to retrieve spotify playlists

Tags: python, spotify

So the user enters the hexcode of a colour and the program uses that to get Spotifyfy playlist.
e.g user enters "red" the program will get "energetic" playlist from Spotify.

```
Hexcode = input("Please enter Colour: ")
```

Im just not sure how to set up the retrieval part from Spotify

These are the Snippets I have:

curl -X "GET" "https://api.spotify.com/v1/browse/categories/dinner/playlists?country=SE&limit=10&offset=5" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer

```
    if Hexcode ==:
    Yellow = #FFCC00
    Blue = #03025D
    Red = #FF0000
    Green = #339900
    Purple = #580C6D


$.ajax({
url: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/" + $("#username").val() + "/playlists",
headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer my_OAuth_Token",
    Host: "api.spotify.com"
},
accepts: "application/json",
type: "GET",
success: function (data) {
    var count = data.items.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < aantal; i++) {
        $("#playlists").append('<option>' + data.items[i].name + '</option>');
    }
},
error: function (data) {
    $("#playlists").append("<option>error</option>");
}
```

});

They're not set up properly and are for different things. I got kind of lost and wasn't really sure what to do.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did it get you?

Comment: i used the developers spotify dash board and got this - curl -X "GET" "https://api.spotify.com/v1/browse/categories/dinner/playlists?country=SE&limit=10&offset=5" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer

Comment: I mean like what code did you use. You should include that in your post as well as the error message you just commented.

Comment: I dont have a full piece yet  i just got different snippets that i was working on. I didnt know how to set it out in the code but ill add them